# What is HL7 V3 and how it can be implemented?

Tags: ionic-framework, hl7, hl7-v3

I am developing a ionic app and have to use HL7 v3.

I tried searching for it, but couldn't found anything much on the technical side. so, my question is:

- What is Hl7 V3?
- How it can be implemented?
- Are there any library for creating and parsing HL7 V3 messages available?

Cheers!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Level_7#HL7_version_3_Messaging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V3 is most likely referring to HL7 Version 3. Version 2.5.1 is currently the most widely implemented version, but more and more systems and organizations are upgrading to V3. Implementing is the same process. You can find various HL7 version documentation here: http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_section.cfm?section=1&ref=nav

Comment: Thanks much! Really appreciate the help!